# How best to detect an unknown number of pulses of an approximate known form over an interval?

Tags: filters, signal-detection, radar, matched-filter, waveform-similarity

It is approximately 30 years since I last studied signal processing, but have lately encountered a problem for which I am confident the solution is well-known in the signal-processing world.  I hope you can help.

I am analysing a signal $q(x)$ in an interval $x \in [a,b]$ which may in some circumstances be little more than $q(x) \approx 0$  $\forall x \in [a,b]$ but in other circumstances may exhibit an unknown number $N$ of 'pulses' whose *exact* form will never be known precisely.  A test-case where pulses are known to manifest with 'centres' at $x = 1,2,3$ is shown in the figure.

[image: Test-case: 3 pulses in q(x) compared with approximating function c(x)]

Though the exact form of the pulses may not be known, a Taylor expansion performed in the vicinity of any pulse centre ('location'), $\rho_k$, for $k = 1,...,N$ results in a first-order approximation of the form of that pulse to be given by

$$
c_k(x) := c_k(x; \rho_k, \gamma) = \frac{1}{\pi}\left[ \frac{\gamma}{(x-\rho_k)^2 + \gamma^2}  \right]
$$

which happens to be the pdf of the Cauchy distribution whose 'shape' is well-known, dictated in terms of 'height' and 'width' by the parameter $\gamma$, and in which **the value of $\gamma$ is known *a priori*** in the problem being considered.  In the ideal case we would impose $\gamma=0$ and the pulse would take the form of the Dirac delta function but, in practice, we may only set $\gamma$ as close to zero as to not inhibit the computational work.

So, were $N$ and the set $\left\{ \rho_k \right\}_{k=1}^N$ to be known, *ex post* a first-order approximation to the signal $q(x)$ for $x \in [a,b]$ is

$$
q(x) \approx c(x) := \sum_{k=1}^{N} c_k(x)
$$

which is also plotted in the figure (though the approximation is 'good' enough that it may be difficult to discern between the two signals).

Before coming to the precise question let us consider the same test-case (though the value of $\gamma$, for the purposes of illustration, has intentionally been set unnecessarily large) where the interval under investigation actually contains no pulse-centres.  This is plotted in the next figure.

[image: q(x), c(x) plotted in the interval x in [1.02,1.98]]

The two pulse 'locations' $\rho = \left\{ 1,2 \right \}$ lie outside the interval $x \in [1.02,1.98]$ considered, however for the requirement that $q(x) \approx c(x)$ to hold in some optimal sense it must be that our analysis obtains at the very least $N=2$ with the corresponding values of $\rho_k$ for $k = 1,2$.  I expect that the comprehensive solution would consider the entire domain $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and return $N=3$ with corresponding values of the set $\left\{ \rho_k \right\}_{k=1}^N$.

With gratitude to those who have reached this far in this post, my question is the following:  What are the optimal techniques for estimating the number $\hat{N}$ and (by consequence) the (estimated) locations $\left\{ \hat{\rho}_k \right \}_{k=1}^{\hat{N}}$ of the pulses?

Given we have a first-order characterisation of the 'form' of the pulse(s) to be detected and ***a priori knowledge*** of one of the two parameters that dictates that form I would expect this challenge should be far from insurmountable.

I look forward to considering the techniques you propose.

Comment: Optimality must be specified in regard to some criterion (e.g. maximizing SNR). Is there a specific cost function that you want to be minimized? Matched filters are the optimal linear filter for maximizing SNR in detecting signals with a known template but unknown delay in stochastic noise. In Steven Kay's Detection Theory book (ch. 12.5) he discusses applying the Generalized Likelihood Ratio Test, computing the maximum likelihood estimate of the delay for an unknown number of signal occurrences, minimizing a sum of a fixed number of cost functions for each event over the domain of N delays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ash says in the comments, the key to this is to define your cost function and subtract the pulse from the peak location and then iterate.

As you indicate by your choice of tags, the best way to find the peak locations (in noise) is to use the matched filter.  Here, because your pulse is symmetric, the matched filter is just another pulse.

The code below **completely ignores that part**. If there's noise on your pulses, you'll definitely want to convolve the incoming (noisy) pulse train with your "prototype" pulse.  The peaks of the result will be the locations of the pulses.

Basically, what the code below does is:

1. Find the first peak location (index).
2. Remove the peak from that location.
3. Check if you've removed all the peaks (not much energy left in the remainder). If there's energy left, goto step 1, otherwise finish.

Below is a plot of the original three pulses in $\color{cyan}{\rm blue}$, and then the signal with the pulses removed in $\color{red}{\rm red}$. I haven't been very careful with making sure I get the test pulse exactly aligned with the real pulses, so it's not completely zero.

[image: BLue: pulses Red: Pulses removed.]

For this noiseless case, the correct pulse locations are given:

> [833, 1666, 2499]

The length of the resulting vector will tell you the number of pulses found.

I'll repeat what I said above, in stronger language: this is a little braindead as a way to find the pulse locations. You're better off using a matched filter for that part. However, iteratively removing each pulse should work regardless of the pulse location mechanism.

---

### Code Only Below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def pulse(gamma, rho, x):
    return np.divide(gamma, np.power(x-rho,2) + gamma*gamma)/np.pi

def find_all_pulses(pulse_train, fraction, one_pulse):
    width = len(one_pulse)
    initial_energy = np.sum(np.power(pulse_train,2))
    pulses_removed = pulse_train.copy()
    pulse_positions = []
    while (np.sum(np.power(pulses_removed,2)) > initial_energy*fraction) and (max(pulses_removed) > fraction*max(centered_pulse)):
        peak_location = np.argmax(pulses_removed)
        pulse_positions.append(peak_location)
        indices = peak_location + list(range(-int(width/2), int(width/2)))
        pulses_removed[indices] = pulses_removed[indices] - one_pulse
        
    return pulse_positions, pulses_removed

N = 5000
x = np.linspace(0,6,N)
diff = x[1]-x[0]

x2 = np.linspace(-1,1,int(2/diff))
pulse_width = len(x2)
half_pulse_width = 500

centered_pulse = pulse(0.01,0,x2)
noiseless_pulses = pulse(0.01,1,x) + pulse(0.01,2,x) + pulse(0.01,3,x)

pulse_locations, removed_pulse_signal = find_all_pulses(noiseless_pulses.copy(), 0.1, centered_pulse)

print(pulse_locations)

plt.plot(noiseless_pulses)
plt.plot(removed_pulse_signal, 'r.')
```

Comment: @Ash, Peter K, thank you for your thoughts.  Indeed the matched-filter looked to me (without much subject experience) to be the tool for the job.  One aspect that we have to our advantage here is that because the pulses are (very) closely approximated by the pdf $c_k(x)$ of a probability distribution we have for $k=1,...,N$ the property $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} c_k(x) dx = 1$ we should be in a position to sample $q(x)$ and numerically compute $N \approx \sum_{k=1}^N \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} c_k(x) dx \equiv \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} q(x) dx$.

Comment: Agree with you both that we need a cost function and SNR is one.  Where I started with this was to try to fit via nonlinear least squares the "prototype" pulse to the incoming signal (starting with a control environment of a single pulse).  I'm not sure I've done this well enough yet but when I started researching the matched-filter I believe I have come to understand that the maximisation of the SNR and the minimisation of the squared errors are closely related.

Comment: Much as in Peter K's suggestion I wondered whether iteratively fitting 'prototype' pulses for as long as SNR was improving and exiting when the present iteration degraded that ratio was the way to go.  I will consider the approach of "deleting" the identified pulses from the signal.  If you can point me to any good resources (not Wikipedia) on the "matched-filter" I would be most grateful.  And if you have any other comments I'd be very pleased to receive them.

Comment: @RickyBoy I intend to respond, but I'm on a work trip until the weekend, so won't be able to give more info until then.

Comment: I am happy to wait for our discussion to continue.  Best wishes for your work trip.

Comment: @RickyBoy Still bogged down in my day job. Regarding a matched filter, check out [Iain Collings' video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ci-EjiMJo3I). Iain gives a good explanation, if video.